# android иконка для приложения

Tags: android

я пытаюсь сделать приложение для android- приложения. Я использую 2 иконки. ic_launcher.png  а для приложения и  ic_nav_bar_logo.png для отображения в строке toolbar.
Иконка для приложения задается в манифесте

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:logo="@drawable/ic_nav_bar_logo">
```

иконка в статус баре задается для каждой активности

```
<activity
            android:name=".Activity"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_nav_bar_logo"
             >
```

при этом после запуска приложения на устройстве в качестве иконки приложения отображается иконка задаваемая для статус бара, но при этом  в диспетчере приложения отображается иконка, которая  должна быть иконкой приложения. Как правильно задать иконку для приложения и для тулбара каждой активновити?

Comment: Попробуйте переформулировать вопрос. Я лично мало что понял. При чём тут статус бар и где что не так отображается?

Comment: К сожалению мой рейтинг не позволяет мне опубликовать изображения. Вопрос в том, что приложение использует  ic_nav_bar_logo вместо ожидаемого ic_launche

Comment: Можно и текстом попробовать объяснить... Попробуйте  android:logo из application убрать

Comment: убрал logo результат тот же

Answer (score 3):

разобрался. добавил в проект (для каждого экрана) икон с расширением 144*144. При этом не пришлось менять икон для navigation bar.

Answer (score 2):

Поместите в ваш `Toolbar ImageView`.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="right" >

    <ImageView
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/yourPicture"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

PS. если вам нужно чтобы в разных `activity` в вашем `toolbar` отображались разные картинки, то в методе `onCreate()` каждого `activity` задавайте программно картинку для вашего `toolbar`